# Error showing Transport Level Information error in SOAP Message

Tags: xml, api, soap, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to process a message using Class Mediator after consuming in wso2. However, getting the below error:

```
Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI
```

Can anyone please guide why this would be an error. For reference below is the xml I am consuming:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <prov>
            <rowID>2106480</rowID>
            <msisdn>745340612</msisdn>
        </prov>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any guidance or help would mean a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you are receiving a SOAP 1.2 message and trying to consume it as a SOAP 1.1 message(Or vice-versa). From the shared message, the namespace `https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` belongs to SOAP 1.2. Hence change the namespace to `https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` if you are using the Content-Type `text/xml` or change the content type to `application/soap+xml`

Comment: can you please guide if we have content-type which consumes both ? considering application/soap+xml is not consuming SOAP 1.1

Comment: @WajihHaider I'm afraid we can't really consume both at the same time, unless you use a Content-Type like application/xml.

Comment: yeah just wanted to ask that if we have any content type where we can consume both, as per what I understood if we put application/xml in content type, it will help us consume both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 ?

Comment: @WajihHaider yes you can consume both as both messages are valid XML payloads.

Comment: When I am putting application/xml, it is giving me mediation error in class for SOAP 1.1, however, when I put text/xml its working fine, any guidance why ?

Comment: @WajihHaider could be due to the way you have implemented the Class Mediator. I can't really tell without seeing the entire flow.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723820/getting-class-mediation-error-when-content-type-is-application-xml